# Why TypeError happens

Tags: python, arguments, typeerror

Why  TypeError happens?

It is a situation such as the following:

```
class kyori():
 def create_distmatrix(seif,arg):
     city_x     = randn(N)    
     city_y     = randn(N)    
     global city_dists
     for i in range(N):
         seif.city_dists.append([])
         for j in range(N):
             dx = city_x[i]-city_x[j]
             dy = city_y[i]-city_y[j]
             seif.city_dists[i].append(sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2))
```

Error Code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\****\Documents\workspace\*****\src\sales.py", line 74, in <module>
   a.create_distmatrix()
TypeError: create_distmatrix() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: Where are you calling `create_distmatrix`?

Comment: Do you want `self` instead of `seif`? The error happens because you call the function without an argument using `a.create_distmatrix()`. Changing `def create_distmatrix(seif,arg):` to `def create_distmatrix(self):` will fix it

Comment: Is your question about why the error thrown in that case (missing argument on function call) is a ``TypeError``? Otherwise the stack trace tells the whole story.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want `self` instead of `seif`. You have a second parameter in the function definition:

```
def create_distmatrix(seif,arg):
```

but you don't pass the arguement when calling it(`a.create_distmatrix()`) resulting in the TypeError. Change

```
def create_distmatrix(seif,arg):
```

to

```
def create_distmatrix(self):
```

to fix the problem. You don't seem to use `arg` anywhere in the function. So you don't need it.

Comment: Thank you to answer me. 
I tried, but can not be an error occurs, such as:`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\***\Documents\workspace\***\src\sales.py", line 74, in <module>
    a.create_distmatrix()
  File "C:\Users\Maeda\Documents\workspace\zyoukan2\src\sales.py", line 34, in create_distmatrix
    seif.city_dists.append([])
AttributeError: kyori instance has no attribute 'city_dists'`How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Try `city_dists.append([])` instead of `seif.city_dists.append([])`

Comment: Thanks!  It is complete.

Comment: You're welcome! You can also [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to credit the answerer and this also gives a small boost to your reputation.